# Get the Id of the matched data from other table. No duplicates of ID from both tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my table A.

```
| Id |  GroupId  |  StoreId  | Amount |
| 1  |    20     |     7     |  15000 |
| 2  |    20     |     7     |   1230 |
| 3  |    20     |     7     |  14230 |
| 4  |    20     |     7     |   9540 |
| 5  |    20     |     7     |  24230 |
| 6  |    20     |     7     |   1230 |
| 7  |    20     |     7     |   1230 |
```

Here is my table B.

```
| Id  |  GroupId  |  StoreId  | Credit |
| 12  |    20     |     7     |   1230 |
| 14  |    20     |     7     |  15000 |
| 15  |    20     |     7     |  14230 |
| 16  |    20     |     7     |   1230 |
| 17  |    20     |     7     |   7004 |
| 18  |    20     |     7     |  65523 |
```

I want to get this result without getting duplicate Id of both table.
I need to get the Id of table B and A where the Amount = Credit.

```
 |  A.ID     |   B.ID    |  Amount |
 |    1      |     14    |   15000 |
 |    2      |     12    |    1230 |
 |    3      |     15    |   14230 |
 |    4      |     null  |    9540 |
 |    5      |     null  |   24230 |
 |    6      |     16    |    1230 |
 |    7      |     null  |    1230 |
```

My problem is when I have 2 or more same Amount in table A, I get duplicate ID of table B. which should be null. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `left join`.  But this is tricky because you have duplicate amounts, but you only want one to match.  The solution is to use `row_number()`:

```
select . . .
from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by amount order by id) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a left join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by credit order by id) as seqnum
      from b
     )b
     on a.amount = b.credit and a.seqnum = b.seqnum;
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, I think simplier and shorter :)

```
select ID [A.ID],
       (select top 1 ID from TABLE_B where Credit = A.Amount) [B.ID],
       Amount
from TABLE_A [A]
```

Comment: I hope you understand why this doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually, I don't.

Comment: This would probably be returning the same row from `b` whenever there are duplicates values in `a`.